# How to update url via javascript in the XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to update the URL inside my javascript function e.g.

```
http://tmaserv.scem.uws.edu.au/chapters/?n=0
http://tmaserv.scem.uws.edu.au/chapters/?n=1
```

and so on.
I've tried using a for loop but it hasn't work.

**Javascript:**

```
function do_exercise () {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();{
        x.open('GET', 'http://tmaserv.scem.uws.edu.au/chapters/?n=0', true);
        x.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status ==200) {
                obj = (x.responseText);
                JSON.parse(x.responseText);
                obj = JSON.parse(obj);
                document.getElementById("section1").innerHTML =
            obj.data
            }
        }
        x.send(null);
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<nav>           
    <button onclick="do_exercise();">Next section</button>      
</nav>
<section id = "section1">
    <h1>Heading One</h1>
    <p>Paragraph One.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: What's the criteria for updating the URL? Every time the button clicked the number in URL increments by 1?

Comment: its something like that i've tried creating a variable and adding it to the end of the url then using a for loop to increment but didn't seem to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var requestNum = 0;

function do_exercise () {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // adjust the GET URL to reflect the new n value and request as before
    x.open('GET', 'http://tmaserv.scem.uws.edu.au/chapters/?n=' + requestNum, true);
    x.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status ==200) {
            obj = (x.responseText);
            JSON.parse(x.responseText);
            obj = JSON.parse(obj);
            document.getElementById("section1").innerHTML = obj.data;
            requestNum++;
        }
    }

    x.send(null);
}
```

Does that make sense? Note that I have removed some curly braces that I presume were a mistake on this line `var x = new XMLHttpRequest();{`.

I would also recommend using [jQuery.getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) for your AJAX call for better browser compatibility and cleaner code.

EDIT: Made my answer far simpler. Thanks to Robert for pointing out where I was completely overthinking things!

Comment: Don't really understand whats going on in the first function, haven't got taught that stuff yet

Comment: This will not work because this is an ajax call and the value of location.search does not change ... hence the page number will never increment.

Comment: That's okay. You don't need to know it yet. It just lets you grab the value of n from the URL, e.g. if your URL ends with `?n=5` then `getParameterByName('n')` will return `'5'`.

Comment: Ah, excellent point @Robert, my mistake. Give me a minute to edit my answer and accommodate that.

Comment: the code instantly skipped to page 11 and after it goes "undefined"

Comment: That should be working after my latest edit. Forgot to `parseInt` the n value (turning it from `'1'` to `1` (an int)), sorry about that!

Comment: Rory - The url returns a json string with data to append to a host page.  The page number isn't maintained in the host page query string. Replace your query string reader with a global var that increments and you'll have a working answer.

Comment: it goes straight to undefined now, I'll try changing some of the code and get back to you and see if it can works. 
Thanks for help

Comment: Ah yes. You're right. There's probably no need to get anything from the query string of the original page at all.

Comment: Made a bit of a, ahem, dog's dinner of this one @DOGGIES52. Robert pointed me back on the right path. Hopefully the current revision will work for you. You can put your button back the way it was before. Sorry about all that!

Comment: Hahaha it works great!! thanks for the help rory :) much appreciated

Comment: Whew, glad I could (eventually) help :D